# UIBarButtonItem Long Press / Short Press

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uibarbuttonitem

I have looked through the existing questions on this subject matter, and there appears to be no answers post iOS 11 (which appeared to break the gesturerecognizers).

Is there a way to detect the short press / long press on a UIBarButtonItem? Apple uses this functionality in Pages, Numbers, Keynote for Undo / Redo.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace your default event handler for the tap event

```
-(void)handlerForBarButton:(UIBarButtonItem*)p_Sender
```

with its extend version

```
-(void)handlerForBarButton:(UIBarButtonItem*)p_Sender forEvent:(UIEvent*)p_Event
```

By inspecting the UIEvent object you can learn, if the event was a long press (tapCount of first UITouch object is 0).

This is my code for a playback rate button that returns the rate to '1x' if the bar button item is pressed longer the about one second:

```
/*
 rateButtonPressed:forEvent:

 */
- (IBAction)rateButtonPressed:(UIBarButtonItem*)p_Sender
                     forEvent:(UIEvent*)p_Event
{
    UITouch*    firstTouch = nil;
    if (   (nil != ((firstTouch = p_Event.allTouches.allObjects.firstObject)))
        && (0 == firstTouch.tapCount))
    {
        self.avAudioPlayer.rate = 1.0;
    }
    else
    {   // Default tap
        if (2.0 == self.avAudioPlayer.rate)
        {
            self.avAudioPlayer.rate = 0.5;
        }
        else
        {
            self.avAudioPlayer.rate += 0.25;
        }
    }
    [WBSettingsSharedInstance.standardUserDefaults setDouble:self.avAudioPlayer.rate
                                                      forKey:@"audioPlayerRate"];
    [self updateRateBarButton];
}
```

Comment: A little Swift extension which basically does the above:


`extension UIEvent {
    var isLongPress: Bool {
        return (allTouches?.first?.tapCount ?? 1) == 0
    }
}`

Unfortunately, this only triggers after the button was released.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
@IBOutlet weak var btn: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, #selector (tap))  //Tap function will call when user tap on button
    let longGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, #selector(long))  //Long function will call when user long press on button.
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    btn.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    btn.addGestureRecognizer(longGesture)
}

@objc func tap() {
     print("Single tap done")
}

@objc func long() {
     print("Long gesture recognized")
}
```

Comment: The issue with this, is that the UI Burton’s image will not behave like the BarButtonItem’s image. Do you have a solution for the animation provided a vector icon?

Comment: have a solution for the animation provided a vector icon: - can you please elaborate

Comment: When a vector is used for the image of a bar button item, it automatically turns blue and has an animation when highlighted. Do you have this functionality incorporated into a UIButton?

Comment: https://www.mattrajca.com/2016/09/07/detecting-long-presses-on-uibarbuttonitems.html

Comment: Also if you want barbutton to  show behaviour like a button simply customize it :--http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBarButtonItem/setBackgroundImage%3aforState%3abarMetrics%3a