# UIBarButtonItem highlighted selector?

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uibarbuttonitem

I have looked through the existing questions on this subject matter, and there appears to be no answers post iOS 11 (which appeared to break the gesturerecognizers).

My previous question ([UIBarButtonItem Long Press / Short Press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54385142/uibarbuttonitem-long-press-short-press)) yielded how to check if the user long pressed, however he user must complete the press by releasing their finger for the selector to be called.

Is there any way to call a function when the UIBarButtonItem is highlighted?

Apple uses this functionality in Pages, Numbers, Keynote for Undo / Redo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't check is `UIBarButtonItem` highlighted or not. It works on `UIControl`, but `UIBarButtonItem` is not subclass of it.